# How to release Bitmap, ReDraw Bitmap, and add it to PictureBox. Without leaking resources or causing much flicker

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a method that draws a Bitmap like so:

```
public void DrawGrid(){
GridBitMap = new Bitmap(x,y);
MyGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(GridBitMap);
MyGraphic.FillRectangle(BackGround, 0, 0, x, y);

//Then using loops I draw various lines like this

MyGraphic.DrawLine(Pen.Black,x,y,xx,yy);

//Then I add the Bitmap to a Picturebox 

PictureBox.Image = GridBitMap;
}
```

My Problem is, every time the method is called. Im using more and more resources. 
How do I release the Bitmap & graphic without causing much flicker?
and prevent the code from consuming more and more resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
using (Bitmap GridBitMap = new Bitmap(x,y))
{
   using (Graphics ScoreGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(GridBitMap)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

if you don't actually need to have a bitmap, why not draw directly into the picture box?
Creating a bitmap each time is time and resource consuming.

Hope this is what you are asking for. The using close ensure that the resource will be released even if there is an exception or if you exit the function prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you could store the Bitmap instead of constructing a new one for every draw call. This should reduce resource consumption considerably. You should only generate a new one when its size is changed (i.e. x and y change, I suppose).

Also, why don't you use ScoreGraphic.Clear to empty it?

And, above all, why don't you just go from the ScorePictureBox.Paint event and draw into the Graphics the PaintEventArgs give you?

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should solve it:

```
using(Bitmap bmp as new Bitmap(x,y))
{
  my code...
} //<--important marker..
```

when the instruction pointer leaves the "important marker" a call to IDisposable of the bmp will be issued - releasing the resource.